# Android: Distinguish between on screen back-key and physical keyboard back key

Tags: android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

Does anyone know if there is a way to distinguish whether <kbd>back</kbd> key was pressed on the screen or on aphysical keyboard? We have a problem with the ASUS Transformer Prime where the android <kbd>back</kbd> key is placed where <kbd>ESC</kbd> should be on the physical keyboard, and people expect it to work like <kbd>ESC</kbd>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out events have a `getSource()` method.

```
if (((event.getSource() & InputDevice.SOURCE_KEYBOARD) != 0) && event.getDeviceId() > 0)
```

or

```
if (event.getDeviceId() > 0 && event.getSource() == InputDevice.SOURCE_KEYBOARD)
```

The first version of this condition is from the android api. the `(event.getSource() & InputDevice.SOURCE_KEYBOARD) != 0)` part.

That should do a pretty good job of telling you if the event was from a physical keyboard.